# SetInterval Keeps Running forever and doesnt stop

Tags: reactjs, canvas, setinterval, clearinterval

I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time. I am making a matrix style themed blog that displays matrix rain effect in the background when the displayMatrix rain state in my Store becomes true, and stops displaying matrix rain effect when displayMatrix becomes false. I need to use setInterval to draw the matrix rain effect, inside the setInterval I call the 'draw' function that has a loop inside that draws the matrix rain characters in the background using canvas tools. The problem I am encountering is that when I change displayMatrix state to true, and than to false later on, the loop keeps on running, and I never see the in the console log 'id being cleared is => #' even after i have changed displayMatrix state to be false. I have tried to mimic the barebones of my code in the following sandbox so you can see the overall structure of the code https://playcode.io/933189/. I am using reacts inbuilt useReducer/useContext hooks in place of redux. Another weird thing I noticed is that in the code sandbox, when i change displayMatrix state to be true, and afterwards turn it to be false, it at least stops the 'run matrix rain drawing code' in the console, but in my original code on VisualStudio Code, I keep seeing 'run matrix rain drawing code' in the console and it runs basically forever until it runs out of memory

```
import React from 'react';
import {useEffect, useContext, useState} from 'react';
import {GlobalStore} from '../Store.jsx';


export function App(props) {

  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(GlobalStore);

  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {

    const draw = () => {
      // pretend 100 is the width of the screen
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i += 1)
      {
        console.log("run matrix rain drawing code");
      }
    }

    // if we want to diplay the matrix rain
    if (state.displayMatrix) {
        // only create an interval when interval does
        // not already exist
        if (intervalId === 0) {
            const id = setInterval(draw, 90);
            console.log("id being set is => " + id);
            setIntervalId(id);
        }
        else {
            console.log("id being cleared is => " + intervalId);
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            setIntervalId(0);
        }
    }
    // if we want to stop matrix rain
    else {
        console.log("id being cleared is => " + intervalId);
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        setIntervalId(0);
    }

  }, [state.displayMatrix])

  return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'CHANGE_MATRIX_RAIN_BACKGROUND_DISPLAY_STATE'})}>Matrix Display {state.displayMatrix ? 'Off' : 'On'}</div>
        </div>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this timeCounter helper class

```
import { setIntervalAsync, clearIntervalAsync, SetIntervalAsyncTimer } from 'set-interval-async/fixed';

export class TimeCounter {
  private interval: SetIntervalAsyncTimer | undefined;
  private onRepeat: () => any;
  private onStop: () => any;

  constructor(onRepeat: () => any, onStop: () => any) {
    this.onRepeat = onRepeat;
    this.onStop = onStop;
  }

  startCounter(milliseconds: number) {
    if (!this.isActive()) {
      this.interval = setIntervalAsync(async () => {
        this.onRepeat();
      }, milliseconds);
    }
  }

  stopCounter(): void {
    if (this.interval !== undefined) {
      this.onStop();
      clearIntervalAsync(this.interval);
      this.interval = undefined;
    }
  }

  isActive(): boolean {
    return this.interval !== undefined;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
export function useCounter() {
  const counter = new TimeCounter(onRepeatCounter, () => null);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!counter.isActive() && defaultDate === undefined) {
      counter.startCounter(1000);
    }
    return () => counter.stopCounter();
  });

  function onRepeatCounter() {
    // Custom functionality
    setResult((val) => val + 1);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

playcode seems to work properly, just press Show More to see the log end.

Comment: No it doesnt, After I make displayMatrix State to be true, than make it false again, than it should show me in the console log "id being cleared is => #" but it doesnt, which means that when I change state to make it false, than it doesnt go into the else block which has the clearinterval(intervalID) to terminate the interval so that there is no memory leakage

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to clarify, when i say i dont see it on the console log, i mean in my VS code, you are right, on the playcode, if I press Show More it does show the line "id being cleared is => #". Another thing to note here is that in my VS code, the button is in another file, I have another file that has code for button, where i change the DisplayMatrix state, I dont think that would be what is causing me problems though, so I just added it in the code where i draw in the playcode to summarize my VS code

Comment: most likely state.displayMatrix is not changing in your VS Code, I would set console.log before `if (state.displayMatrix) {`

Comment: Ok, i did console log state.displayMatrix inside of the for loop inside the draw code, and you are right. I think what happens is that set interval creates a snapshot of the code and in that snapshot of the code, it has the state.displayMatrix to be true, so it keeps on running in the background until it runs out of memory. In my VS code, the loop keeps running for a few minutes until i see "id being clared is => #", unlike the online code sandbox where it shows that immediately. Is there any way around that?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Q-man it looks like the draw function blocks useEffect... Try to comment `console.log("run matrix rain drawing code");` or replace it by actual canvas drawing.

Comment: How can the draw function block useEffect? i dont understand what you mean by that. Even if lets say I add canvas drawing in there in place of the console.log("run matrix rain drawing code), how does that change anything related to the setinterval? the setinterval will still keep running forever. Also, I am using canvas in my VS code anyway

Comment: draw function itself is supposed to be async, because it's run by setTimeout, but console.log can block, I couldn't find if it's sync or not in different browsers... So you've tried and remove console.log from draw, but it changes nothing?

Comment: Sory for the late response, was working on another problem. Yes, I have removed console.log and it changes nothing. I will add async to the Draw() function and see if that does the trick